# Screen rotation not working as intended on some devices

Tags: android, mobile, unity-game-engine, screen-rotation, autorotate

This issue seems to occur on some Android devices, notably the Kindle Fire. I'm currently developping an app that runs in Landscape Right and Landscape Left modes, but it seems on some Android devices it starts up on one side then cannot be rotated afterwards.

I'm using Unity 4.3.4f, and my settings are set to support both landscape modes and is set on Auto-Rotation.

Also, I've made sure the problem isn't about the auto-rotation being locked on my device, so it must be something related to my app settings.

Any reason this works on some devices and not on others ?

Note : This issue doesn't occur on iOS devices.

UPDATE : This issue occurs only sometimes on some devices. Sometimes rotation will work fine, other times it just will stay stuck in one direction. Same build, upon killing the app and restarting it may work. Kinda confused as to why this is happening !

Answer (score 0):

Check if in this devices you dont have the rotation blocked in settings.

Comment: I have checked that and that is not the issue. The rotation is unlocked and functionnal in other applications/home page.

Comment: Any ideas ? Still struggling with this !

Comment: Why you define your activities in Android Manifest?

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean... I haven't worked with the Android Manifest, I believe Unity generates it for me or something.

Comment: In Android Manifest you have an option to put layout orientation in your activities.

Comment: Okay, what would be the way to go with Unity to edit this manifest ?

Comment: This i dont know but try to see here: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AndroidMobileAdvanced.html

Comment: Tried this. For some reason it doesn't work. Updated question.